# Expander combined with GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, expander, gridsplitter

I’m trying to split my WPF window into two “areas”, top and bottom.

- The top area contains a grid.
- The bottom area contains an expander.

Between the two areas should be a GridSplitter which the user can use to resize the areas.
The content of each area should use the full high of the area.

[image: expected]

By default, the expander is expanded.
When the user closes the expander, the bottom area should reduce its height to the height of the collapsed expander.

This is my code:

```
<Window
    x:Class="App.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Shell" Height="800" Width="1200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="MainContentGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Top area -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">1</Button>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">2</Button>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">3</Button>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">4</Button>
            </Grid>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Background="Black" 
              ShowsPreview="true"
              ResizeDirection="Rows"
              Height="5"></GridSplitter>
            <!-- Bottom area -->
            <Expander Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" IsExpanded="True" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border Background="Red" Height="Auto" MinHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
        <!-- Application Status Region -->
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static local:RegionNames.StatusRegion}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Two things are not working:

- The expander does not all available space (does not change its height)
  [image: expander not using all space available]
- When I close the expander, the GridSplitter does not allow the top area to use all the space available.
  [image: top area does not use all space available]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you interact with `GridSplitters` they set concrete relative or absolute `Height`/`Width` values on the grid row/column definitions. So once you collapse the `Expander` you should set its row's `Height` to `GridLength.Auto`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Your solution works. But I had to change another thing… the GridSplitter was in its own row… I removed that row and added it to the row which contains the expander.